# Drop into an Interpreter anytime in Python

Tags: python, debugging

I know how to drop into an interpreter with `pdb` and `IPython`, but this requires me knowing beforehand exactly where I want to stop.  However, I often run number crunching scripts that take minutes to hours, and I would like to know exactly what it's progress is.  One solution is to simply put lots of logging statements everywhere, but then I either inundate myself with too much information or fail to log exactly what I want to know.

Is there a way to initialize a listener loop that under some key combination will drop me into the code wherever it currently is?  Think CTRL+Z but leaving me in Python rather than Bash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [signal module](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) to setup a handler that will launch the debugger when you hit control-C or control-Z or whatever.. SIGINTR, SIGSUSP.

For example, define a module `instant_debug.py` that overrides SIGQUIT,

```
import signal
import pdb

def handler(signum, frame):
  pdb.set_trace()

signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, handler)
```

Then make a script

```
import instant_debug
import time

for i in xrange(1000000):
  print i
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

At any point during execution, you can jump into the code by typing `CTRL+\`, examine the stack with `u` and `d` as in normal `pdb`, then continue with `c` as if nothing ever happened.  Note that you will only jump in at the end of the next "atomic" operation -- that means no stopping in the middle of a giant C module.

Comment: Problem is, how do you do this on windows?

Comment: Much respect to duckworthd for the edit that expanded my terse answer into a full fledged good answer. I wish there was a way to re-target the positive rep I gained to you instead. For lack of that, I leave this follow-up comment for future readers of this question - duckworthd answered it better than I. Respect.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, check out the signal module link in my response. There are a couple Windows specific signals you can wait for that'll do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
def main():
    i = 1000
    while True:
        print "Count Down %s" % i
        time.sleep(1)
        i -= 1

try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass # Swallow ctrl-c
finally:
    code.interact("Dropped into interpreter", local=globals())
```